# Google Sheets Script to Insert a Word Between First and Last Names On Submit from Google Forms

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I have a check in form with Google Forms for my business which populates the Form Responses 1 tab of my Google Sheet.  Clients enter their full name as a short answer.  We use Zapier to create contacts from this sheet in Google Contacts. In order for my employees to differentiate clients from personal contacts, I am trying to insert " Client " in the space between the first and last name.

Is there a way to do this only on new rows? The find and replace script I made (below) does it repeatedly such that it will keep inserting Client infinitely in the spaces of older entries. Using "underscoreClientunderscore" works, but should we want to export contacts later on, this won't let us use first and last names.

```
   function replace() {

   var range =  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Form 
   Responses 1").getRange("B:B");

  var v = range.getValues();
  for ( var r = 0; r < v.length; ++r) {
  v[r][0] = v[r][0].replace(/ /g, " Client ");
  }
  range.setValues(v);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the string function [`indexOf(searchstring)`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof.asp) to check if the word client is already present in the cell. If so, then skip the cell, else modify it.

If the function cannot find the string it will return "-1". The below code checks for it using an if statement. 
The modified code is as follows:

```
function replace() {

  var sheet =  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Form Responses 1")
  var range = sheet.getRange(1, 2, sheet.getLastRow(), 1)
  var v = range.getValues();
  for ( var r = 0; r < v.length; ++r) {
    if(v[r][0].indexOf(" Client ") == -1){
      v[r][0] = v[r][0].replace(/ /g, " Client ");
    }
  }
  range.setValues(v);
 }
```

I also modified the code a bit to process only up to the last entry and not all the rows in column B.

Final thoughts: You can also achieve this process automatically as the entries are submitted using [installable triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable), they have the added advantage of running on only the lastest entry using [event objects](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#form-submit). 
Hope that helps!